# E-mail a direct link to a newly created Dynamics CRM Account in Outlook

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm creating an application that, based on a webform, creates an Account in MS Dynamics CRM 2011. If everything is going fine and the account is created succesfully, I want to send the manager an e-mail containing a direct link to the newly created Account.

Currently I'm using something like: `https://mycrm.com/main.aspx?etc=1&id=%7B2FCE55B6-9513-E211-BAA7-001DD8B71E5F%7D&pagetype=entityrecord`. However, if I put this link in an e-mail it will open a new browser window to view the page. The client uses CRM from Outlook so I was wondering if there is a way to directly send Outlook to the created account using a generated link?

Comment: We use the "Set Regarding" feature of activities to send an email linked to the new account. It's not a link per se, but it does include a clickable link at the bottom of the message that people can click on to navigate directly to the related item.

Comment: Okay, will that open a new browser window, or will they be redirected within Outlook?

Comment: Try doing it manually in Outlook - it will bring up the Outlook webform. With that said, we haven't been able to get it to work from a server-side workflow, but there may be workarounds for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should reconsider your (your customer's) workflow. Why are you sending an email in the first place? If it is because you want the manager to do something with the account (confirm, approve, accept, review ect.) then you should probably consider creating a task in stead named "review new account". You can assign that task to the manager and that will give a "link" in outlook that points to the account. Also you can track the completion of the task and act on that e.g. changing the "account status" from "under review" to "active".
Its just a thought.
IMO you should stay away from using emails internally as they are very hard to act on in CRM.